# Why my iOS device not detecting my voice?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator

in my viewdidload i wrote

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0], AVSampleRateKey, 
                                           [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                                           [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                           [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                           nil];

    NSError *error;
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

    if (recorder) {
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [recorder record];
        levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 
                                                      target:self 
                                                    selector:@selector(levelTimerCallback:) 
                                                    userInfo:nil 
                                                     repeats:YES];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
    }
}
```

another implementation method is

```
- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer 
{
    [recorder updateMeters];

    const double ALPHA = 0.05;
    double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
    lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;  

    if (lowPassResults < 0.95)
        NSLog(@"Mic blow detected");
    else
        NSLog(@"Person spoked");
}
```

when i run my code on the simulator using my mac mic it works and when i spoke it comes to the condition "Person spoke", but when i run my app on real IOS device it doesn't detect any voice although i had switched on allow microPhone for my app in "Settings"

What should I do?

Comment: i had edit my question @Raptor

Comment: Is `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"]` allowed? I doubted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use these following line of in your viewDidLoad

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
```

This will work for your iOS devices.